# Unity 2D physics - ball passes through object instead of bouncing back

Tags: game-physics, unity-game-engine

I followed this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AhTYpNCFhpA) to create a Breakout game using Unity. Everything is okay apart from the contact between the ball and blocks. Instead of the ball bouncing back in the opposite direction when it collides with a block, it moves in the same direction. I am not too sure what is causing this issue. I am using version 5.2.3f1 but version 4.6.1f1 was used in the tutorial. I've uploaded my project to this  [link](http://wikisend.com/download/853376/Blocks.zip)

Comment: did u add a physics material to the blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure the objects have Rigidbody components
- Make sure the objects have Colliders
- Make sure the objects are on Layers which can collide with each other (see Edit\Project Settings\Physics 2D: Layer Collision Matrix)
- Make sure you are moving your objects using Physics (`obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(...);` or by applying forces/impulses). It **won't** work if you just modify `obj.transform.position`
- Assuming objects A and B are colliding, make sure **not** to destroy either of them the same frame they are colliding. If you destroy A inside its OnCollisionEnter2D handler, B may never know it collided with A. You may use delayed destruction like `Destroy(gameObject, 0.1f);` (will destroy `gameObject` after .1 seconds)

Comment: I am quite new to Unity. I've done the above, but it's still not working. Were you able to check the code I uploaded?

Comment: Yes I looked into it now and added another checkpoint to the list. If you follow that, it'll work. Also (though unrelated to your question), when starting the ball of through the SPACE key, make sure that code is only executed once, not per frame. When holding SPACE your ball keeps accelerating until light speed ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. May I ask, what about if I want the ball to pass through the paddle without colliding (bouncing back)?

Comment: You may temporarily disable the paddle's collider like `paddle.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;` and reenable it later.